# Управление объектами в Python при работе с атрибутами и статическими атрибутами?

Tags: python, c++, ооп, классы, выделение-памяти

Как работает следующий код:

`class MyClass:
pass
p1 = MyClass()
p1.atrib1="1"
p1.atrib2="2"
p1.atrib3="3"

p2 = MyClass()
p2.atrib1="1"
p2.atrib2="2"

print(p1.atrib3) // ok
print(p2.atrib3) //error`

-как у разных объектов одного класса может быть разное количество аттрибутов?

Как это работает с точки зрения внутреннего устройства, учитывая, что в Python - Конструктор не препятствует добавлению новых аттрибутов уже существующим объектам, но карантирует, что каждый созданный объект будет иметь определенный набор аттрибутов.

Как работают  Аттрибуты объекта и Атрибутты класса (статические аттрибуты) - которые доступны для всех объектов - по сравнению с другими ЯП?
Напимер, в с++ -есть поля и переменные метода - разница в области видимости, есть статические переменны - которые дорступны только при обращении к классу и не доступны для объектов. Как я понимаю, аттрибуты объекта в Python - это аналог поля в с++ (но мне все так же не понятно, как они могут быть свои у каждого объекта), а статические аттрибуты - это как раз аналог статического поля в с++, но в Python - есть возиожность обращаться к ним именно через конкретные объекты?

P.S -  в тегах к вопросу указан тег С++ - т.к хотелось бы понять разницу идей на примере сравнения как раз с с++.

Comment: Питон - язык с динамической типизацией. В нем нет объектов класса. Вместо них есть что-то вроде таблиц `::std::map< ::std::string, ::std::any >`.

Comment: @user7860670 Это детали реализации, но объекты то есть как же нет то

Comment: @CrazyElf Объекты-то есть, но они не являются экземплярами класса в том смысле, в котором это бывает в языках со статической типизацией, таких как С++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы добавляете поля в экземпляр класса. Питон это позволяет. У каждого экземпляра класса могут быть свои добавленные поля. При инстанциировании экземпляр объекта получает поля класса и может добавлять к ним какие-то свои поля. Но при этом каждый экземпляр,  после того как он инстанциирован, живёт сам по себе уже, один экземпляр не знает ничего про поля, добавленные в другой экземпляр.

C-подобные языки насколько я понимаю, если и позволяют что-то добавлять "на ходу", то делают это не совсем штатными способами. Они более строгие, чем Питон, где "на ходу" можно делать почти что угодно обычным присваиванием.

И "статическими" называются методы и поля класса, а не экземпляра класса. Их можно использовать без инстанциирования экземпляра.

Comment: ок, понял. А что насчет  аттрибутов объекта и атрибутты класса (статические аттрибуты) - я правильно уловил суть?

Comment: Я немного дополнил ещё до того как прочёл доп. вопрос. Насколько я помню в питоне несколько хитро с полями, но в целом обычно во всех языках статические штуки - это то, что существует без экземпляра и доступ к ним идёт через имя класса. Атрибуты это кстати особое понятие, его не надо путать с полями класса.

Comment: Хорошо бы кто поставил минусы объяснили за что именно